# How to get unique column indicator in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, database-indexes

For some reason I am unable to include the "unique" column in my return list.  Any suggestions?

**This query works:**

```
SELECT 
        m.tbl_name as table_name,
        il.name as key_name,
        ii.name as column_name,
        case il.origin when 'pk' then 1 else 0 END as is_primary,
        il.partial,
        il.seq as seq_in_index
    FROM sqlite_master AS m,
        pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
        pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
    WHERE 
        m.type = 'table'
```

**But This query fails**

```
SELECT 
        m.tbl_name as table_name,
        il.name as key_name,
        ii.name as column_name,
        case il.origin when 'pk' then 1 else 0 END as is_primary,
        case il.unique when 1 then 1 else 0 END as is_unique,
        il.partial,
        il.seq as seq_in_index
    FROM sqlite_master AS m,
        pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
        pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
    WHERE 
        m.type = 'table'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite (and other databases) `unique` is a [keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) (reserved word), so you must enclose it inside backticks or square brackets or double quotes:

```
case il.[unique] when 1 then 1 else 0 END as is_unique
```

but you could also write:

```
il.[unique] as is_unique
```

Comment: nearly bruised my forehead on this one. ;)  Thank you for the kind reminder...